.NET iOS UseInterpreter and AOT
We are in the process of migrating a Xamarin.iOS app to .NET iOS, in the early stages we found we were getting crashes with the Release config that were solved by adding <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>.
Our understanding was that this had the affect of disabling AOT compilation, and the errors we were getting would have been related to assemblies that weren't compatible with AOT.
Now our migration has matured we're keen not to lose out on the potential performance improvements AOT could bring. However if we re-enable AOT is there a technique we can use to identify the assemblies that aren't compatible?


The Mono interpreter overcomes these restrictions while abiding by platform restrictions. It enables you to interpret some parts of your app at runtime, while AOT compiling the rest.

So, when you set UseInterpreter to True, it enable the interpreter and it AOTs everything it can in all assemblies while other bits of code restricted by AOT are still compiled to MSIL and JIT compiled at runtime.
Another way to enable the interpreter is to use   MTouchInterpreter MSBuild property. The following code has the same effect as <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>

use the following example to AOT compile all assemblies, while still allowing the interpreter to perform dynamic code generation:

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <MtouchInterpreter>-all</MtouchInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>


To be concluded, either using
<UseInterpreter>True</UseInterpreter> or <MtouchInterpreter>-all</MtouchInterpreter> is fine as it AOTs everything it can in all assemblies, while some bits of code (such as generics, reflection)  will be interpreted.
For more info, please refer to Enable the interpreter.

Yeah thats fine, but is there a way to determine which assemblies shouldn't be part of AOT?

<UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter> is okay from the doc. You could see my updates.
